# How to get tracking number from ebay sandbox through ebay api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ebay-api

The ebay trading api is not giving the tracking number in response for an item sold on ebay sandbox. The item has a tracking number on ebay sandbox.

Comment: Tracking number as in shipping confirmation tracking number or as in an ebay order id?

Comment: As in shipping confirmation tracking number

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the getorders API with eBay. Will require user token for that account and then use ShippingDetails response.

http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetOrders.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use: [ShipmentTrackingDetailsType in Trading API](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/xml/docs/Reference/ebay/types/ShipmentTrackingDetailsType.html)

And the operations which have this available are: CompleteSale, GetItemTransactions, GetOrders, GetOrderTransactions, GetSellerTransactions, GetSellingManagerSaleRecord (documented on the same page)

Comment: It is working for me on live environment but not in sandbox environment.It is fetching all the information about the item except tracking number in sandbox environment.

Comment: what operation are you using?